# Remove the Alt+F1 hotkey from Gnome Shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

I want to remove the functionality of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> in Gnome Shell. I've tried poking around `gconf-editor` and `dconf-editor`, as well as the normal Keyboard settings (super → "keyboard" → click Keyboard), but couldn't find anything. I also wasn't able to find anything when I searched on Google. How can I do this?

Comment: Please accept an answer (with the green tick button) rather than putting "resolved" in the title.

Comment: @Nero gris: Philip Kendall is right: on [SE], we don’t put answers into questions.  If don_crissti’s answer solved your problem, you should “accept” it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.  Otherwise, answer your own question (click on “Answer Your Question”) and describe your resolution.  (If you can identify the specific update to Gnome that did the trick, that would be great.)  You should then accept your answer.  Since you are a new user with a low reputation score, you may need to wait a few hours (or even days?) before the system will allow you to accept your own answer.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Since the "solution" was essentially "wait for upsteam to 'fix' it", I didn't think that warrented it's own answer, but I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but I was told that posting the answer in the question post is unacceptable.

Pretty much the solution was "it started working as expected". That is to say the "super → "keyboard" → click Keyboard"" thing I tried before, which failed due to the required option being absent previously, succeeded because the required option was now present.

Answer (score 4):

In Gnome 41, I also had to do

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.apps-menu apps-menu-toggle-menu "[]"
```

(or you can modify the key using the dconf-editor UI)

Answer (score 3):

That's one of the wm keybindings - you can change it via `dconf-editor` if you navigate to
*org / gnome / desktop / wm / keybindings*:

[image]

and select/click on *panel-main-menu*:

[image]

---

You can also do that in CLI via `dconf` or `gsettings` e.g.

To `get` the current keybindings:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu
```

```
['<Super>s', '<Alt>F1']
```

To `set` different keybindings use the same syntax - it's an array of quoted strings, separated by a comma and a space, everything enclosed in double quotes:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['<Super>s']"
```

Comment: That's really weird. I went to that spot in dconf-editor, but the "panel-main-menu" entry only had Super listed. Alt+F1 wasn't there, like it is in your screenshot.

Comment: @Nerogris - not sure what your gnome version is but the _<ALT>F1_ combo has been there for at least four years now...